# When an authoritative server is found in the NS record, is the A record checked for the ip address or not?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-zone, ns-record

I am trying to understand what NS records are, how glue records form part of it and what happens afterwards? As far as I understand the NS record contains the hostname/s of the authoritative nameserver or those which might hold info on where to find it. Assuming no caching:

1.) How does the recursor know if the NS record points to the authoritative nameserver or directs the recursor to another nameserver? Or are both things the same? I mean the entries in the NS record are just 'best effort' nameservers which might have the hostname of the authorithative nameserver or might point to nameservers which may or may not have information on the ip address of the authorithative nameserver?

2.) Once the recursor finds an entry in the NS record in a particular nameserver (e.g. TLD nameserver), does it check the A record to find the corresponding ip address or does it repeat the whole DNS process again (querying the root nameserver, then TLD nameserver, etc.)?

3.) How does "glueing" exactly work, I'm aware it's related to avoid recursive queries but are the glueing ip addresses found in the A record? In case of no glueing, does it mean that for 2.) the whole DNS process starts all over again for that hostname (coming from the NS record I guess)?

4.) In Cloudfare's explanation for the NS record, the example includes an @ and I've seen it too in this example Zone DNS, [Example Zone File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuuZc.png) , what does the @ or leaving that column blank actually mean?

I'd really appreciate it if someone can help me out understanding this since I'm having a hard time trying to figure it out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to understand what NS records are, how glue records form part of it and what happens afterwards?

Glue records are not part of `NS` records.

Glue records, or glues, are `A` and `AAAA` records, and the only thing different is that they are published at the parent side of the delegation instead (in fact in addition of) being published at the authoritative side, which is the children of the delegation.

Most of your questions are difficult to answer because you are not using specific examples. Things depend a lot on using either an authoritative or recursive nameserver for queries, so it is not clear what you are doing.

> 1.) How does the recursor know if the NS record points to the authoritative nameserver or directs the recursor to another nameserver?

`NS` records always point to authoritative nameservers, that is their definition.

RFC 1034 §3.6:

> ```
>             NS
>            the authoritative name server for the domain
> ```

(Of course a client has no way to check if that is true or not, in the sense that, without DNSSEC, this could be changed in the path or by the recursive resolver you are querying).

> I mean the entries in the NS record are just 'best effort' nameservers

No. I don't know from where you get the "best effort" thing, but `NS` records are authoritative nameservers and nothing else.

> 2.) Once the recursor finds an entry in the NS record in a particular nameserver (e.g. TLD nameserver), does it check the A record to find the corresponding ip address or does it repeat the whole DNS process again (querying the root nameserver, then TLD nameserver, etc.)?

A `NS` record gives a name. That name needs to be resolved to one or more IPv4 or IPv6 addresses, so any user (client) of that, needs to resolve that name to an IP, which happens through the exact same mechanism as anything else, except of course that the cache is heavily used there (and hence major nameservers names are in cache worldwide as used by many domains, so their IP is not often resolved). So, yes, it starts back at the root... except of course in the presence of glues, and when they can be accepted.

> 3.) How does "glueing" exactly work, I'm aware it's related to avoid recursive queries but are the glueing ip addresses found in the A record? In case of no glueing, does it mean that for 2.) the whole DNS process starts all over again for that hostname (coming from the NS record I guess)?

Simple. Imagine you have `example.com` domain, which is delegated from `com`. So `.com` nameservers have `NS` records pointing `example.com` to its nameservers. Now imagine that you choose the "in-bailiwick" situation where the domain nameservers are themselves "under" the domain, aka the nameservers are `ns1.example.com` and `ns2.example.com`. Those would be the `NS` records at parent. But with all that, resolution is impossible. You ask parent "who is responsible (authoritative) for `example.com`" and you get back "contact `ns1.example.com` and `ns2.example.com`" but to do that you need to resolve those 2 names and hence, starting from root again you come again to "who is responsible (authoritative) for `example.com`" so endless loops.

In case like these there needs to be glues, aka `A`/`AAAA` records at the parent, that the client gets back at the same time it gets the `NS` reply back.

Let us take a real example, with traces as they are now, the domain `icann.org`.

First, what are `.org` nameservers?

```
$ dig org. NS +short
c0.org.afilias-nst.info.
d0.org.afilias-nst.org.
a2.org.afilias-nst.info.
b0.org.afilias-nst.org.
b2.org.afilias-nst.org.
a0.org.afilias-nst.info.
```

Let us pick any of these and ask for `NS` records of `icann.org`:

```
$ dig @b2.org.afilias-nst.org. icann.org NS

; <<>> DiG 9.18.4 <<>> @b2.org.afilias-nst.org. icann.org NS
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Sending:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 62392
;; flags: rd ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 4c1ae1af0f0d1e3f
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;icann.org.     IN NS

;; QUERY SIZE: 50

;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 62392
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 3
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;icann.org.     IN NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
icann.org.      1h IN NS a.icann-servers.net.
icann.org.      1h IN NS b.icann-servers.net.
icann.org.      1h IN NS c.icann-servers.net.
icann.org.      1h IN NS ns.icann.org.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns.icann.org.       1h IN A 199.4.138.53
ns.icann.org.       1h IN AAAA 2001:500:89::53
```

As expected, the `AUTHORITY` section gives you the list of `NS` records. But here you have an `ADDITIONAL` section. Why? Because one of the 4 nameservers for `icann.org` is `ns.icann.org` so it is in-bailiwick. To be able to resolve it, the parent (`.org` nameservers) have to publish glues too, which are `A`/`AAAA` records... and they are in the `ADDITIONAL` section, hence the client can now contact `ns.icann.org` immediately without further DNS query, because it has already the IP addresses.

Looking at that, one may wonder why doesn't everyone just use glues and nothing else, as it seems "better" (faster, no dependencies, etc.)?
In fact, it is not better, it has advantages and drawbacks (which is why in most cases, a good domain would use some in-bailiwick nameserver and some out-of-bailiwick).
Among drawbacks:

- the IP addresses have to be managed at the registry; if they change, a change needs to be done (outside the DNS, typically with EPP) by the registrar of the domain on behalf of the client; this is often forgotten and creating lots of problems
- even if `icann.org` is fully DNSSEC enabled, the reply from `.org` authoritative nameservers does not sign the records in the `ADDITIONAL` section, which means they can be changed on the path without the change being detected

> 4.) In Cloudfare's explanation for the NS record, the example includes an @ and I've seen it too in this example Zone DNS, Example Zone File , what does the @ or leaving that column blank actually mean?

Both are not really part of the DNS, but conventions called "master zonefile format", loosely defined in §5 of RFC1035:

> The last two forms represent RRs.  If an entry for an RR begins with a
> blank, then the RR is assumed to be owned by the last stated owner.

and

> @               A free standing @ is used to denote the current origin.

It just means, that if you are writing the zonefile for zone `example.com` for any record you can either write `example.com.` (here the final dot is very important, if you forget it, it means relative so a name of `example.com` in this file really means `example.com.example.com.`) or `@` it is the same thing, so up to you to decide which you choose. Why is it useful? Because for some generic zones, you can have the exact same zone content for multiple zones. If you write the zone content with `@` and hence do not have to write down the zone name inside the zonefile you can reuse the same file for multiple zones, simplifying maintenance.

As for the "leaving the column blank", again it is a shortcut you can use or not.

The following two are the same:

```
foobar IN A 192.0.2.42
foobar IN TXT "I am foobar"
```

and

```
foobar IN A 192.0.2.42
       IN TXT "I am foobar"
```

(amount of spaces is just for alignment, no specific amount is needed outside of at least one)

or even:

```
foobar IN TXT "I am foobar"
 IN A 192.0.2.42
```

You have less to write in the second case, but with the drawback that you can NOT any more move the lines around easily, as the second line needs the context of the first one.

This is an implementation detail of the first nameservers (bind), and depicts how the content of the zone is written in so called textual zonefiles. Other nameservers have to follow that convention and support the same format.

But you never do a DNS query for `@` or for an empty name (that case is not even possible). So all of that is hidden inside nameservers.

Comment: @ Patrick Mevzek You sure are a DNS master! Thanks a lot for your answer. It's a lot to take in for sure but it's amazingly well explained! If I want to learn more about DNS and dig, is there any resource or book you can recommend me? I would like to find a resource with all the gritty details of DNS but also find out how to see this in practice with dig.

Comment: I would recommend you to start with https://powerdns.org/hello-dns/ : it is a recent introduction (so many documentation are outdated...) on all things DNS (but as far as I see doesn't speak about glues :-(), by someone very knowledgeable. Then if you want something still recent but more difficult, look at RFC 8499 which defines lots of DNS terms and gives pointers to other resources. It speaks about glues and in-bailiwick. Then the real core documents are RFC 1034 and 1035 but they are 40 years old, full of errors and ambiguities...

Comment: https://powerdns.org/dns-camel/ is also a recent attempt to list all RFCs related to DNS, but by itself is not a guided tour, so it seems more to demotivate people in fact :-). If you want to be "on the edge" or at least on par with recent developments, do learn about DoH (DNS over HTTPS), DoT/DoQ (... over TLS, over QUIC), QNAME minimization, and DNSSEC. But DNSSEC by itself is a big topic. Best is also if you can run a nameserver locally on your box, even more than one to test delegations, etc. do live queries and so on.

Comment: The article at https://educatedguesswork.org/posts/dns-security/ is also the start of a series of 7 articles about DNS, which should be good (didn't read it all yet, but it is recent, and by someone known). It may be more targeting the use of the DNS in the WebPKI and alternatives like "blockchain" domains, but I am sure you can learn new things from there too. It is more a view on "security" but using glues or not (aka depending on external names) has also obvious impacts on the global security of a domain regarding its global resolution.

Comment: thanks a lot again! Just another thing. In your main answer, you said "Things depend a lot on using either an authoritative or recursive nameserver for queries". Would you mind to expand on this if you can? Also, the thing I'm still trying to get if you initially make a request for example.com, the recursor will first query the root (.) nameserver. But then, does it check the NS records for .com TLD nameserver and make another DNS query based on this or would it check the A records for the ip address of the .com TLD namerver?

Comment: Would this happen exactly the same at the .com TLD nameserver when looking for the ip address of the authorithative nameserver for example.com?